# Is it possible to have chunked Http GET requests?

Tags: http

I am trying to write a simple proxy. I just want to know whether it is possible to have chunked Http GET requests?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no and yes simultaneously. GET requests don't have any content, so they obviously cannot use chunked transfer encoding (there is nothing to transfer). However the response to a GET request can contain a body that is encoded using chunked transfer encoding. So whenever there is a body, chunked transfer encoding may be used. The [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) page has more information and also links to the corresponding [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1).

Comment: Almost. GET can have a request body; it's just that the spec doesn't specify what it means, and recipients are almost guaranteed to ignore it.